# glob pattern that must hit all parts

Tags: shell, gradle

I am trying to do things the easy way and I am striking out.  I have these files

```
local.localfile.properties
local-localfile.properties
local_localfile.properties
localfile.properties
```

I need a glob pattern that will match the first three, but not the fourth.  I have this

```
**/local[.-_]*
```

but it matches all 4.  Now the regex

```
(local)[\.|\-|_]
```

does what I want and possibly as soon as I can dig up an example of this

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html#exclude(org.gradle.api.specs.Spec)

I may go that route instead, but until then, is there a way to get glob to do what i want?

Comment: Try: `local[._-]*` though it is better to post a problem that is easily reproducible

Comment: Your problem is the hyphen, which needs to be the first or last character in the bracket expression, or it becomes used as part of a range.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching: "A ‘-’ may be matched by including it as the first or last character in the set."